# What the meaning of $1 before the Filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
function copy_nfs_files {
        [ -f /proc/self/mountstats ] && cp /proc/self/mountstats $1/proc-self-mountstats.$2 >/dev/null 2>&1
        [ -f /proc/net/rpc/nfsd ] && cp /proc/net/rpc/nfsd $1/proc-net-rpc-nfsd.$2 >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

This bash function copies two files `/proc/self/mountstats` and `/proc/net/rpc/nfsd`. What is the meaning of `$1/proc-self-mountstats.$2`? I see `$1` just before file name and `$2` at the end of file?

I understand that `$0` is the basename, `$1` the first arg, `$2` the second arg, and so on. What I want to know is what it will yield when they are using like `$1/proc-self-mountstats.$2`. Let's suppose `$1 = 123` and `$2 = 100`. You mean it will become `123/proc-self-mountstats.100`?

I googled around to get the meaning but did not get anything around on this.

Comment: Sure, why would you assume the semantics change?

Comment: It's evidently a typo for `"$1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to know is what it will yield when they are using like `$1/proc-self-mountstats.$2`. Let's suppose `$1 = 123` and `$2 = 100`. You mean it will become `123/proc-self-mountstats.100`?

Yes, that's right. The expanded values are joined together with the literal parts to form one big string.

Answer (score -2):

Outside a function $1 stands for the first argument of your script.
Inside a function $1 stands for the first argument to the function.

Comment: Outside a function it's the script's first argument. Inside a function it's the *function's* first argument.